# How to get the name of the Foreign Key tables for a model instance in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get the name of the tables that are foreign key fields for my model instance. For example, I know that I can get data about my fields by using `instance._meta.concrete_fields` or by getting the name of fields in `instance._meta.get_fields` but I do not have any idea about getting the foreign keys fields table names. I wonder if you help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the `_meta` (`Options`) API of the related model for the `db_table` attribute:

```
related_field.related_model._meta.db_table
```

For example:

```
for field in instance._meta.concrete_fields:
    if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
        print(field.related_model._meta.db_table)
```

Comment: I checked and now I understand that this statement gives us the name of the table in database. I want the table name in Django models.

Comment: @GhazalehKharadpoor Each Django model results in a DB table unless abstract. And either you can provide the table name yourself in the `Meta.db_table` or Django automatically as `<app_name>_<class_name_lowercased>`. In both cases, the `_meta` API gets you the table name correctly. So your question is a bit ambiguous. What do you meant by "table name in Django models" ?

Comment: Yeah I know that I can convert the name to the Django models but I thought It must be a better way. 
I meant that for example if the Django table name is "CaseFile", it is saved as "app_name_casefile" in the database.

Comment: @GhazalehKharadpoor I don't understand your question. If you want to name the DB table yourself, you can do that by putting the name as `Meta.db_table`.